# How to keep a value from a activity untill app flows starts again

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I really don't know how to write the title in the right way, but I will try to explain the issue. I'm working on an app that has like six activities in a sequence, the login is the first activity and once the login is successful I pass the user name to the second activity via bundle and across all the other activities. On the last activity, once the process is successful, it has to go back to the second activity. But, it has to keep the user name. As right now, when the app goes to the second activity, it crashes because it is not getting the user name value, even with the bundle. it is kind of how to make a bundle from two different activities to the same activity.

Comment: Can you edit with the second activity code? Why it crashes can be for many reasons. I would open a new instance if the second activity and remove the backstack that is not needed at this point.

Comment: Use a singleton to store global data instead of trying to pass things around like that.

Comment: Use **SharedPreferences**, to store data values. check the link for reference. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/3096016]

Comment: I wil try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*VERY EASY,*

Use ***viewpager*** with ***fragments*** inside activity ***instead of Activities(Activities also takes much loading time then fragment)***

You can use ***custom non-swipable viewpager*** which can be found on google easily.
- Use Viewpager,
- Disable Swiping,

Use click callback on fragments, or **EventBus** to pass data between activity and fragment.

i would suggest using **Eventbus** as it a best way for sending and receiving data from-to anywhere.

You can ask me anything more if you are facing any problem.

Comment: I am new to android, do you have a turotorial for beginners you could share?

Comment: Sure, just for viewpager adapter use this
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

and for event bus, 
https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/5604

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to resolve your issue

**First Method**

Once Login is successful pass in the username using a bundle to the next activity

OnCreate method of MainActivity class retrieve the username

Override the BackPressed method, add a bundle with the username when navigating back to a previous activity to avoid the app from crashing

**Second Method**

This one is probably less tedious

Use shared preferences to store the username once Login is successful and retrieve the username when needed.

These are two of many ways to solve your problem. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, if you find it useful please accept the answer.

Comment: I am new to android, do you have a turotorial for beginners you could share?